# jquery dynamic class name update doing image delay

Tags: javascript, css

Inside a page I am having a TR on which when user click it change it's color to blue and arrow color to white. This is achieved by changing elements' class dynamically.

But due to this what happen is, when user click on TR user saw image loading delay. How to preload that CSS image.

```
this.className = this.className + " active";
```

CSS

```
.table td.arrow div {background-image:url("../stuff/arrow.png");}  
tr.active td.arrow div { background-image:
url("../stuff/arrow_active.png"); }
```

[image]

**Update**
One more thing want to update that static content is getting loaded from other server.

Comment: using sprites would be the best solution here. Less HTTP requests + no preloading problems: http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/ , http://www.alistapart.com/articles/sprites

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser only loads images from the CSS that are shown. So you could place your arrow_active image in a element, that is visible but has no opacity.

But i would suggest you use sprites: Less HTTP requests + no preloading problems: [css-tricks.com/css-sprites](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites) , [alistapart.com/articles/sprites](http://alistapart.com/articles/sprites)

You could solve your problem like this with pure CSS.

http://jsfiddle.net/Q6dTf/

Alternatively you could use a :before pseudo element if you dont want to add a new HTML element.

Comment: this looks something like a solution. Let me have a try and get back .

Comment: I tired this but no success, Image get loaded. But when I clicked the TR it again loaded the image :(

Comment: Yes I did something wrong, now tested working . Thanks man =)

Answer (score 0):

As @meo said you are probably better off using sprites, but in case you want to preload images you can just create a dummy `Image` instance that loads the image into the browser's cache.

Like:

```
var preload = new Image();
preload.src = '../stuff/arrow_active.png'; //triggers the download
```

In case you want to wait for the preloading to wait for the page to build you can listen for the `load` event that the `preload` will fire when it has finished loading the file (be careful as this is complicated terrain).

Comment: as of now i have individual images, in future will use sprite.